# Apache DELETE request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php-5.3

I have a problem. My webserver sinds 403 responses when I send a DELETE request. I don't want to delete the thing in my request, I just need to know that the method used was delete. How do I configure my webserver that it doesn't send those 403 messages anymore? I don't want WebDAV enabled or something like that. I just want to know if the request method was DELETE (in my php file, but it isn't executed because of the 403).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I read it should be something like this:

```
<Limit DELETE>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

Comment: Note that for Apache>2.4, the directive has changed. `Allow from all` must be replaced by `Require all granted`. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration.