# PUT & DELETE requests - Laravel app on a shared hosting

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I've made a laravel cms app which I'm trying to deploy on a shared hosting. Locally, it runs great.

I’ve saved all laravel app files/folders (except public) in the root under ‘adminCore’ folder. Then, I’ve copied all laravel’s public folder content to public_html/test_page folder.

When I run it (testpage.mywebpage.com), I can log in, I can 'see' all views, connect and read from the database - I can even store new data. However, if I try to edit or delete, data (from database), I get a 403 error, i.e. PUT and DELETE requests get denied.

Since I'm fairly new to this problematics, I'd really appreciate if you could explain why is this happening and/or how should this be solved. Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170377/apache-delete-request may be applicable

Answer (score 1):

Laravel doesn't actually use "PUT" and "DELETE" requests in forms. Instead, a hidden form field is added to the form when you specify a `PUT` or `DELETE` action:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

The issue could be that you're actually using `PUT` and `DELTE` as actions in your form, when you should be using a hidden field like above.

The form `action` should be `POST` and then then add the hidden `_method` field with the value of your desired action (as above). Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="route/url">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
    <!-- other form fields here -->
</form>
```